# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Crashing on shutdown

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub-efi

I'm new to Ubuntu and after installing it on an laptop of mine I've been fault finding my way through a few errors. Apologies if these aren't articulated properly, if not please tell me where, I'm keen to learn as much as I can:

1. Initially the installation froze once it was completed and I was asked to reboot, necessitating a hard rest,
2. Once started in recovery mode I was able to install the graphics drivers but again whenever I tried to reboot after installations the laptop froze,
3. I found out that Ubuntu was starting in legacy mode as opposed to EFI. Downloaded Boot Repair, disabled secure boot, and successfully altered the BIOS boot, please find the Boot Repair results here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SyWVHVCjQW/
4. Each time the laptop restarts after a hard reset I'm able to get into Ubuntu through the GRUB recovery menu,
5. Whenever I restart the laptop it freezes,
6. I can just shut the laptop down normally. However, it always boots up in the GRUB recovery menu,

I've been diving through forums for the past three days trying to figure this out and none of my fixes seem to work. If anyone can help me:

1. How do I fix the reboot issue so it doesn't freeze?
2. How do I stop it from always booting into GRUB on start up?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is a one question/multiple answer format. You seem to be trying to ask multiple questions at once. That doesn't work well here. Please edit your Question to ask about a single topic that the gurus here can answer for the benefit of future readers. Use the 'Search' box at the top of the page, too - many thousands of questions have already been answered.